# Understanding MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have this small query and I would appreciate if someone could clarify this.

Let's say I have 2 tables in my database

```
Table 1: t1
     NUM
     1 
     1  
     1
Table 2: t2
    NUM
     1
     1
     1
```

If I perform Inner Join or Left Join or Right Join
    I get 9 results
    My query is as follows:

```
select t1.num from  t1 inner join/left join/right join t2 using(num);
```

Can someone please tell me why is the query displaying 9 result always irrespective of the join I am using

Answer (score 0):

if you have the same table and data in both the places then all the joins will return you the same result, kindly go through the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to understand the joins